# Rails: Google analytics tracking with rack-tracker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-analytics

I've been using Google Analytics to track pageviews on [my website](http://learnbyreading.herokuapp.com/), and now I want to use it to track event.

Specifically, I want to send event to GA to log the book's info when they visit a book's `show` page.

---

I look through the docs at rack-tracker, https://github.com/railslove/rack-tracker, and here is what I did

In `application.rb`, I add

```
config.middleware.use(Rack::Tracker) do
  handler :google_analytics, { tracker: 'UA-48000000-0' }
end
```

In `BooksController#Show' action, I add

```
tracker do |t|
  t.google_analytics :send, { type: 'event', category: 'book', action: 'click', label: @book.title, value: @book.isbn }
end
```

However, I don't see any event coming up in Google Analytics dashboard, I want to know (both in dev and production env), where I made it wrong?

Comment: I always forget to restart the server in order to get the changes in application.rb to take affect :)

Comment: @cqcn1991 3 years later I'v got the exact same issue and no clue how to debug and test why it's not working correctly. I doubt it but if you have found a solution after this time I will be happy yo hear it :)